# How to successfully pass credit card information to heroku using SquareAPI? Getting NSCocoaErrorDomain issue code 3840

Tags: ios, json, swift, heroku, square

I'm trying to create a iOS app that processes credit card payments using the Square API.

I'm using a Heroku server as the backend.

My issue is when I try to process the credit card payment using the Card Entry view controller.  I'm getting a NSCocoaErrorDomain issue code 3840 saying the "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."

Here is the snippet of code I used to set up the card entry form:

```swift
let theme = SQIPTheme()

theme.errorColor = .red
theme.tintColor = Color.primaryAction
theme.keyboardAppearance = .light
theme.messageColor = Color.descriptionFont
theme.saveButtonTitle = "Pay"

let cardEntryForm = SQIPCardEntryViewController(theme: theme)

return cardEntryForm
```

And here is the snippet of code I used to process the payment:

```swift
ChargeApi.processPayment(cardDetails.nonce) { (transactionID, errorDescription) in
   guard let errorDescription = errorDescription else {
   // No error occured, we successfully charged
      completionHandler(nil)
      return
    }
}
```

Also here is the ChargeApi (code that is doing the processing of the payment):

```swift
class ChargeApi {
    static public func processPayment(_ nonce: String, completion: @escaping (String?, String?) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: Constants.Square.CHARGE_URL)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let json = ["nonce": nonce]
    let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
    print(json)
    request.addValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = httpBody
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error as NSError?{
           if error.domain == NSURLErrorDomain {
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  completion("", "Could not contact host")
               }
            } else {
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 completion("", "Something went wrong")
               }
            }
        } else if let data = data {
          do {
             let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]
             if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   completion("success", nil)
                }
             } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion("", json["errorMessage"] as? String)
                 }
             }
          } catch {
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion("", "Failure")
             }
          }
      }
    }.resume()
}
```

I believe the way it works, is that after submission the credit card info is wrapped up in a value called a "nonce" and it is sent to the Sqaure API to be processed.

The API looks for this "nonce" in the following json format ["nonce": (some nonce value)].

However after successfully following the steps in the InAppPaymentsSample example:

https://developer.squareup.com/docs/in-app-payments-sdk/quick-start/step-2

I'm trying to something similar with my test app as far as talking to the Heroku server and sending test card information to the server, however I'm getting this NSCocoaErrorDomain issue.

Please help.

Comment: Please share the JSON code.

Comment: `let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8); print(responseString)`. Give us the output/read the output.

Comment: Sure, here is the json code that I'm using:                                                                 let json = ["nonce": nonce]
let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
 print(json)

Comment: Here is the output:  ["nonce": "cnon:CBASEEEAzXjv62HDnsAoydKwjZI"]

Comment: Also for that responseString snippet of code, I get a welcome page (from the server) that is in html code.  The code is very very long for me to paste.  But it looks like I can connect to the server.  I'm thinking that it is maybe a JSON issue (that's my guess anyway).

Comment: `addValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`, maybe with `application/json` (lower case), that could be why you have a HTML Page instead of JSON. But, I'd suggest to copy/paste that HTML page into a new file (on your mac) Reponse.html, and open it with Safari/Chrome. It could have informations, or paste it here.

Comment: My response on webpage : \n \n \n \n \n \n \n
\n
\n
Heroku | Welcome to your new app!
\n
\n

Refer to the documentation if you need help deploying.
\n
\n
\n
\n \n